# Proof on brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If B is a standard brownian motion, then

$$X_t = 3t - 2B_t$$ is also Brownian motion. And what is mean and variance of this $X_t$.

I would like to prove it. But I can’t. Help me to do please.

Comment: $X_t$ is not a Brownian motion since it has a drift term?

Comment: No this is true. Because this is given as a property in a book. But I don’t understand why it is. Thus, I want to prove it. @RhysSteele

Comment: Which book is this? If this is really written in a book then that book is using a definition of Brownian motion that differs from the normal one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This $X_t$ is not a Brownian motion, but it is a Gaussian process.  The mean is $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[3t - 2B_t] = 3t - \mathbb{E}[2B_t] = 3t$ and the variance is $$\mathbb{E}[(X_t-3t)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(2B_t)^2] = 4 \mathbb{E}[B_t^2] = 4t.$$

It isn't a Brownian motion because its mean is not equal to $0$.

Comment: There is a such thing as a "Brownian motion with drift."

Comment: Yes, and a Brownian motion with drift is not a Brownian motion.  They're obviously closely related concepts, but the standard definition of a Brownian motion includes that the mean is $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is the solution to diffusion equation (with $X_0=0$):
$$
X_t = \int_{0}^{t}\sigma(x)dB_t + \int_{0}^{t}\mu(x)dt
$$
If you equate the first stochastic integral to the second term in your solution, and the second integral to the first term, you get $\sigma(x) = -2, \mu(x) = 3. $